# Sort DateTime List by Time

Tags: c#, list, sorting, datetime, lambda

I have a datetime list and I would like to sort it using a lambda expression if possible.

My list:

```
6/19/1979 8:00:00 AM
5/5/1980 7:00:00 PM
10/20/1982 5:00:00 PM
1/4/1984 6:00:00 AM
```

The output should be in this order:

```
1/4/1984 6:00:00 AM 
6/19/1979 8:00:00 AM
10/20/1982 5:00:00 PM
5/5/1980 7:00:00 PM
```

Comment: For future post please try to avoid tags in title and all sort of "thank you notes". Feel free to discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Strange that the dates used in this question are identical to those on this page: http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort-datetime

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Simply, `OrderBy` the `TimeOfDay`:

```
var list = dateList.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay).ToList(); 
// ToList added in response to comment.
```

Comment: When I use your method I get this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.DateTime>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.DateTime>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"                       CODE: Time is List<DateTime>:                                                 Times = Times.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay);

Comment: @user2138160 Add a `ToList` call at the end. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Above will work only if all the date are same, in case the date are also different you should do the following...

```
var sortedDates = dates.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

or else Don't want to use, or don't know Linq then you can go for following..

```
static List SortAscending(List list)
{
list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
return list;
}

static List SortDescending(List list)
{
list.Sort((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));
return list;
}
```

Comment: Note that the sample data posted by the OP disregards dates in favour of times.

Comment: this linq solution is in fact the only working to me.the other don't sorted well Datetime i added .last() for get oldest update and  it work well when other don't .

Answer (score 1):

`list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));` Where list is you List variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result=dates.OrderBy(d=>d-d.Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

use  this solution

```
list<DateTime> YourList=new  list<DateTime> ();
.
.
.
YourList.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Date).ThenByDescending(x=>x.TimeOfDay).ToList()
```